# jquery stop function (not animate)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, events

essay. bold. essay

essay. bold. essay

essay. bold. essay

essay. bold. essay

mouse event function :

```
function stat(){
 $('p').mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).find('b').css({background:'yellow',color:'red'});
  $(this).mouseleave(function(){
   $(this).find('b').css({background:'transparent',color:'black'})
  })
 })
}
```

windows resize jquery code:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
 if( $(window).width() < 480 ){
  $('p').find('b').css({background:'red',color:'white'});

  // stopped stat() function !..
 }else{
  $('p').find('b').css({background:'transparent',color:'black'});
  // start stat() function !..
  stat();
 }
})
```

I need; stop function stat(). stat () function does not stop when the work first time

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vcode/0qgchj9a/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to turn off your event listeners.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
 if( $(window).width() < 480 ){
  $('p').find('b').css({background:'red',color:'white'});

  // stopped stat() function !..
  $('p').off('mouseenter').off('mouseleave');
 }else{
  $('p').find('b').css({background:'transparent',color:'black'});
  // start stat() function !..
  stat();
 }
})
```